# How to check the version of scipy

Tags: python, scipy

How can I check the version of `scipy` installed on my system?

Comment: import scipy; print scipy.version.version

Answer (score 127, accepted):

```
In [95]: import scipy

In [96]: scipy.__version__
Out[96]: '0.12.0'

In [104]: scipy.version.*version?
scipy.version.full_version
scipy.version.short_version
scipy.version.version

In [105]: scipy.version.full_version
Out[105]: '0.12.0'

In [106]: scipy.version.git_revision
Out[106]: 'cdd6b32233bbecc3e8cbc82531905b74f3ea66eb'

In [107]: scipy.version.release
Out[107]: True

In [108]: scipy.version.short_version
Out[108]: '0.12.0'

In [109]: scipy.version.version
Out[109]: '0.12.0'
```

See [SciPy doveloper documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/dev/#version-numbering) for reference.

Answer (score 16):

Using command line:

```
python -c "import scipy; print(scipy.__version__)"
```

Answer (score 12):

on command line

```
 example$:python
 >>> import scipy
 >>> scipy.__version__
 '0.9.0'
```

Answer (score 3):

From the python command prompt:

```
import scipy
print scipy.__version__
```

In python 3 you'll need to change it to:

```
print (scipy.__version__)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `pip list`

This will give you a list of all installed Python modules with version number.

Use `pip list | grep scipy` to filter out all unnecessary information about other packages.