# module 'scipy.signal' has no attribute 'stft'

Tags: python, scipy

According to docs, there is a

```
scipy.signal.stft
```

but when trying to access that function I get the error from the title. The function is documented [here](http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.signal.stft.html#scipy.signal.stft).

Also, scip.signal.istft does not exist either. Any suggestions?

Comment: Which scipy version do you have? The docs seem to describe v1.0.0. (My v.0.18.1 did not have the function either.)

Comment: [check the version](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21385196/6521116)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs:
`New in version 0.19.0.`

http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.signal.stft.html#scipy.signal.stft

Answer (score 1):

You need to check your module version, you van refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21385196/how-to-check-the-version-of-scipy).

stft func is added in the [SciPy 0.19.0](http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/release.0.19.0.html#scipy-signal-improvements), check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17925381/6521116) to upgrade your module to the newsest version.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade to v 0.19.0. I tried many ways to do that but always got 0.18 instead. So to upgrade to 0.19.0 just simply do

```
pip install scipy==0.19.0
```